What are the conditions for the uniform circular motion of this small ball?
As shown in the figure, one end of the rigid rod is a small ball, and the other end of the rod is supported on a plane. The gravitational field of the Earth is vertically downward, thus forming a torque as shown by the green arrow. The pole will tilt downwards with the fulcrum as the center under the action of this torque. One end of the pole is not allowed to leave the fulcrum E.

Under what conditions will the small ball move uniformly in a circular motion around point A?
I think that due to the torque generated by gravity, the horizontal force acting on the ball and the frictional force acting on the fulcrum must balance the weight torque (display with red arrows). Only then will the ball move uniformly in a circular motion. I don't know if it's right or not.
The ball will be confined to remain at a fixed distance from a certain point on the plane. there is any free motion of the ball.

Could you add some details about the constraints? Is the massless pole rigid? Is the constraint at ground a cylindrical hinge? Is the hinge non-ideal, so that friction occurs with rotational velocity? I'm starting writing an answer assuming so

Did you make that image yourself, if so, how?

@basics The pole is ideal and rigid. The supporting point is a cylindrical hinge, right. The pole support can rotate freely, but it will not leave the support point,

@AlbertusMagnus I created it using Geogebra software.

Perhaps you are thinking of a ball suspended by a rope from a ceiling? The ball swings in a circle. What you have shown won't do that. The ball will fall over and hit the floor.

@mmesser314 I consider it to be a rigid rod supporting the ball and moving uniformly in a circular motion.

Seems task is under-specified. Where is other body located which attracts the ball ? How does gravitational vector field looks like ? Does action goes on the surface of Earth or in micro-gravity when attracting body is somewhere located on the axis ?

@AgniusVasiliauskas  The gravity field is parallel to the downward direction of the Earth's gravity field along the z-axis.

There doesn't seem to be any force (or component of a force) on the ball towards the centre of a horizontal circle in which the ball is supposed to be rotating, so I have to agree with mmesser's comment.

@PhilipWood What I asked is under what conditions the ball will move uniformly in a circular motion.

@enbin "under what conditions the ball will move uniformly in a circular motion": when the ball is resting on the plane and has been given an initial tangential push and, if there is friction between the ball and the plane, a continuing tangential push equal and opposite to the frictional force. As I've tried to explain – see my comment on basics's answer – the ball won't stay 'in the air' with the rod at an angle to the horizontal.

@PhilipWood Do you mean that the ball cannot move uniformly in a circular motion? I have modified the attached image, I'm not sure if you can see it. I added the torque formed by gravity and the torque formed by the horizontal force applied to the ball. Is it possible to move uniformly in a circular motion when these two distances are balanced?

no extra information is required. And the answer you need is the one I wrote, and someone (someone of you I guess) downvoted

@PhilipWood Constraints are part of the systems. With a cylindrical hinge the only degree of freedom is rotation about the axis. Before commenting (and downvoting) you'd better have a review of basic classical physics

I also suggest the OP to avoid modifying the text of a question, if the subject of the question changes

@enbin Am I misunderstanding the question – does the box in your diagram have a top to it, which can exert a downward force on the ball?

@basics  I am thinking about how to express my question. Sorry, as English is not my native language, I cannot express my question well.

@PhilipWood  That's just a way of drawing a three-dimensional diagram, without any tops or boxes.

@enbin As I thought. Just checking. Thank you.

Let's analyze the system as a rigid body (6 degrees of freedom) constrained in the origin with a cylindrical hinge (5 degrees of constraint: no displacement of the hinged point (3), no rotation except for the rotation around the axis (2)).
Dynamical equations for a rigid body
The full dynamics and constraint reactions can be solved with the equations of motion for the momentum and the angular momentum, namely
$$\begin{cases}
\dot{\mathbf{Q}} = \mathbf{R}^{ext} \\
\dot{\boldsymbol{\Gamma}}_H = - \dot{\mathbf{x}}_H \times \mathbf{Q} + \mathbf{M}_H^{ext} \ ,
\end{cases}$$
setting the pole in the origin, $H \equiv O$, so that $\dot{\mathbf{x}}_H = \mathbf{0}$.
Dynamical equations using cylindrical coordinates
Set of coordinates. Now, driven by the geometry of the problem, it could be useful to use cylindrical coordinates $(r, \theta, z)$, with a set of material (following the same rigid motion of the system) orthonormal vectors $\{ \hat{\mathbf{r}}, \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}, \hat{\mathbf{z}}\}$. Choosing the rotation angle $\theta(t)$ around the axis as the single free degree of freedom of the system, the angular velocity reads
$$\boldsymbol{\Omega} = \dot{\theta} \hat{\mathbf{z}} \ ,$$
and the time derivatives of the vectors of the material basis read $\dot{\hat{\boldsymbol{x}_i}} = \boldsymbol{\Omega} \times \hat{\mathbf{x}}_i$ or explicitly,
$$\dot{\hat{\boldsymbol{r}}} = \dot{\theta} \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \quad , \quad \dot{\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}} = -\dot{\theta} \hat{\boldsymbol{r}}  \quad , \quad \dot{\hat{\boldsymbol{z}}} = \mathbf{0} \ .$$
Position, velocity and acceleration of the mass. The position of the mass can be written as
$$\mathbf{r}(t) = R \mathbf{\hat{r}}(t) + H \mathbf{\hat{z}} \ ,$$
while velocity and acceleration can be readily evaluated through direct derivation,
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{v}(t) & = R \dot{\theta}(t) \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}(t) \\
\mathbf{a}(t) & = R \ddot{\theta}(t) \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}(t) - R \dot{\theta}^2(t) \hat{\boldsymbol{r}}(t) \ .
\end{aligned}$$
Momentum, angular momentum and their time derivatives. The expression of the momentum and the angular momentum thus read
$$\begin{aligned}
 \boldsymbol{Q} & = m \mathbf{v} = m R \dot{\theta} \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \\
 \boldsymbol{\Gamma}_0 & = m \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{v} =
m (R \mathbf{\hat{r}} + H \hat{\mathbf{z}}) \times R \dot{\theta} \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} = m ( R^2 \mathbf{\hat{z}} - R H \mathbf{\hat{r}} ) \dot{\theta} 
\end{aligned}$$
and their time derivatives
$$\begin{aligned}
\dot{\mathbf{Q}} & = mR (\ddot{\theta} \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} -\dot{\theta}^2 \hat{\mathbf{r}}) \\
\dot{\boldsymbol{\Gamma}}_O & = m R^2 \ddot{\theta} \hat{\mathbf{z}} - m R H (\ddot{\theta} \hat{\mathbf{r}} + \dot{\theta}^2 \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} ) \ . \\
\end{aligned}$$
Actions. Now, we just need to evaluate the external actions, forces and moments (both "active" and "reactive", no distinction), acting on the system. These actions are due to:

the weight of the mass:

force $\mathbf{W} = - m g \mathbf{\hat{z}}$,
moment $\mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{W} = \dots = m g R \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}$


the reactions of the constraint:

force $\mathbf{F} = F_r \mathbf{\hat{r}} + F_{\theta} \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} + F_z \hat{\mathbf{z}}$
moment $\mathbf{M}_0 = M_r \mathbf{\hat{r}} + M_{\theta} \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} + M_z \hat{\mathbf{z}}$, with $M_{z} = 0$ for ideal hinges, or $M_{z} = -c_{z} \dot{\theta}$ for linear model of friction. If an external driving torque $C^e_z$ is there, we need to sum it to $M_{z}$.



Equations of motion. Thus, putting everything together, separating all the components of the force and moment equations, the 6 equations of motion become:
$$\begin{cases}
r: & - m R \dot{\theta}^2 & = F_r & \\
\theta: & m R \ddot{\theta} & = F_{\theta}  \\
z: & 0 & = -mg + F_z \\
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
r : & - m R H \ddot{\theta} & = M_r  \\
\theta : & - m R H \dot{\theta}^2 & = M_{\theta} + m g R \\
z : & m R^2 \ddot{\theta} & = M^{friction}_z  + C^e_{z} \\
\end{cases}$$
Uniform circular motion
Now, we can prescribe the uniform circular motion $\theta = \Omega t$, $\dot{\theta} = \Omega$, $\ddot{\theta} = 0$ and find the conditions required to produce that motion, namely the driving torque required and the reactions of the constraint (that must be strong enough to support them). Inserting the conditions on $\theta$ in the general expression of the governing equations we can easily get get
$$\begin{cases}
r: & - m R \Omega^2 & = F_r & \\
\theta: & 0 & = F_{\theta}  \\
z: & 0 & = -mg + F_z \\
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
r : & 0 & = M_r  \\
\theta : & - m R H \Omega^2 & = M_{\theta} + m g R \\
z : & 0 & = M^{friction}_z  + C^e_{z} \\
\end{cases}$$
i.e. radial force of the constraint provides the required centripetal force, no tangential force without angular acceleration, z-component of the reaction equilibrates the weight; no momentum along the radial direction with no angular acceleration, momentum along the tangential direction of the constraint must equilibrate both the contribution of weight and "centrifugal" force, driving torque equilibrates friction along the z-direction of the rotation axis.
Conclusions
In order to have a uniform circular motion:

with a non-ideal hinge with friction, a driving torque is required to equilibrate friction; friction transforms the mechanical energy of the system into heat, the driving torque most provide the same dissipated power;
with an ideal hinge with no friction, no driving torque is required. Energy conservation holds, and the mass keeps rotating with constant velocity without any external driving force;

Constraint actions are so that:

the radial component of the force is the centripetal force of the uniform circular motion
the component $M_{\theta}$ equilibrates the moment due to weight and centrifugal force of the mass


Your writing is too professional, I don't quite understand it. Is your conclusion that two torques are balanced?

I edited the end of the answer with some descriptive conclusions

But how does the force balance when the ball is subjected to gravity? Will it not fall?

@basics "the radial component of the force is the centripetal force of the uniform circular motion" Assuming "the force" to be the force that the rod exerts on the ball, the radial component of that force is radially OUTWARDS; it is not the centripetal force needed for circular motion. This assumes that the rod is under compressive stress; it has to be for the vertical component of the rod's force on the ball to balance the gravitational pull on the ball. We conclude that the ball can't be in a steady state of uniform circular motion with the rod at a non-zero angle to the horizontal.

no way. Forces acting on the whole system is radially inwards (centripetal), and the truss has tension (not compression) stress (along with other internal actions)

@PhilipWood the radial force is pointing inwards, as anyone who attended first years of high school should know, and as you may realize looking at the minus sign in front of the expression of $F_r$. The truss has axial tension (along with other internal forces and moments). The sign of forces and moments exchanged between parts of the systems can be easily obtained with the third principle of dynamics.

"the radial force is pointing inwards" The radial force on the ball NEEDS to be inwards to support circular motion, but if the rod is under compression it won't provide an inward radial force on the ball. If the rod were under tension it could provide such a force, but it couldn't provide an upward force component to balance the gravitational pull on the ball. On the subject of high school Physics, you might try drawing vector addition diagrams for the forces on the ball in the two cases: rod under compression, rod under tension.

the rod is in tension. Stop. You can add your answer with a diagram of forces. If it's right, I'll upvote when I'll be at a PC, if it's wrong I'll downvote it and add mine

@basics. I can't add an answer because the question is closed. But I'm sure you see my point that if the rod is under tension the vertical component of the force that it exerts on the ball is downwards, and can't possibly cancel the downward gravitational pull on the ball. The ball will fall (in addition to any circular motion it might have) and will 'hit the deck'.

just vote to reopen

@PhilipWood If I'm reading the question right (because it's extremely unclear), I'm fairly sure that the ball cannot sustain any angle equal to or above the horizontal.

@basics The vertical (z) forces only cancel if the rod is below the horizontal. If they are above they add. Also this system is a spherical pendulum which has 2 DOF instead of 5.

The OP has changed the original question. Before I wrote this answer,  I asked if the constraint at ground is a cylindrical hinge, and he answered yes. I can't spend too much time updating answers to changing questions, and this should not the way this site work

The system described in the original question was a rod connected to a cylindrical hinge at ground and with a mass at the other end, with a generic angle with respect to the axis of rotation. Thus, 1 dof, and this answer follows

@basics Sorry, my mother tongue is not English, so I didn't describe my thoughts clearly at the beginning. I also did not have a correct understanding of "cyclical hinge". I apologize again for this.

@basics  This website allows one person to submit several answers to a question. I suggest you provide another answer based on the modified question.
